# Laravel 4 won't show default error messages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and I've been using this [book](http://daylerees.com/codebright). It says that it has some default validation error messages, for example:

- The username field is required.
- The email field is required.
- The password field is required.

For some reason this messages won't appear, instead this is what it's shown:

- validation.email
- validation.min.string
- validation.confirmed

Why the default error messages won't show?? (I know I can make some custom ones)

This is my controller:

```
public function sign_up()
{

    // Fetch all request data.
    $user = new User;
    $data = Input::all();
    $validator = $user->isUserValid($data);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $user->email    = $data['email'];
        $user->password = $data['password'];
        $user->save();
        echo('Data was saved.');
    }else{
        // Collect the validation error messages object.
        return Redirect::to('/sign-up')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

}
```

That uses this method used from the model:

```
  public function isUserValid($data){

    // Build the validation constraint set.
    $rules = array(
        'email'    => 'email|required|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:5|confirmed'
    );

    // Create a new validator instance.
    return $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);    

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your error messages contain validation.email, the key of the validation localization, then your laravel app didn't load or doesn't have access to the localization folder.

check if you haven't removed `app/lang/en` and there should be a file called `validation.php` with all the default validation responses.

alternatively you could also [set the messages on the fly](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages), but using the localization file `validation.php` is way better. anyway, you'd go this way:

```
$messages = array(
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
);

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: I just checked and validation.php is inside `app/lang/en` and it has all the messages. I remembered that I changed the language of the app, just put it back to english(en) inside `app/config/app.php` and it works again. Thanks!